# What is uniform integrability?

Tags: real-analysis

I know two definitions of uniform integrability:

1. (Rudin - Real and Complex Analysis). Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a positive measure space. A set $\Phi\subset L^1(\mu)$ is called *uniformly integrable* if to each $\epsilon>0$ corresponds a $\delta>0$ such that
   $$\left|\int_E fd\mu\right|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$
   whenever $f\in\Phi$ and $\mu(E)<\delta$.
2. (Royden & Fitzpatrick - Real Analysis) Same thing except that $(1)$ is replaced by
   $$\int_E|f|d\mu<\epsilon.$$

Are the two equivalent? Clearly 2. implies 1., but I am not sure whether or not 1. implies 2.

The second one a lot more convenient to use in proofs, but sometime I don't know if "uniformly integrable" only assumes the first one.

Comment: Try to prove 1 implies 2.

Comment: As a technical side note, Royden actually defines uniform integrability for a collection of measurable functions instead of integrable ones (see [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2004384/169085)), though he gives this equivalence as an exercise (5.6.50, p. 96).